# AWS Lambda and inaccurate memory allocation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I realized that I need to allocate much more memory than needed to my AWS Lambda functions otherwise I get:

```
{
"errorMessage": "Metaspace",
"errorType": "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError"
}
```

For instance I have a Lambda function with 128MB allocated, it crashes all the time with that error whereas in the console it says "Max memory used 56 MB".
Then I allocate 256MB, it doesn't crash anymore but it always give me a "Max memory used" between 75 and 85MB.

How come? Thanks.

Comment: The person who down voted could maybe explain the reason.

Comment: I just ran into the same problem. Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: I have similar issues

Comment: The real question:  Can these settings be changed?

Answer (score 18):

The amount of memory you allocate to your java lambda function is shared by  heap, meta, and reserved code memory.

The java command executed by the container for a function allocated 256M is something like:

```
java -XX:MaxHeapSize=222823k -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=26214k -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=13107k -XX:+UseSerialGC -Xshare:on -XX:-TieredCompilation -jar /var/runtime/lib/LambdaJavaRTEntry-1.0.jar
```

222823k + 26214k + 13107k = 256M

The java command executed by the container for a function allocated 384M is something like

```
java -XX:MaxHeapSize=334233k -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=39322k -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=39322k -XX:+UseSerialGC -Xshare:on -XX:-TieredCompilation -jar /var/runtime/lib/LambdaJavaRTEntry-1.0.jar
```

334233k + 39322k + 39322k = 384M

So, the formula appears to be

85% heap + 10% meta + 5% reserved code cache = 100% of configured function memory

I honestly don't know how the "Max Memory Used" value reported in Cloudwatch logs is calculated. It doesn't align with anything that I'm seeing.

Comment: You can find it out with `ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getInputArguments()`.

Answer (score 3):

What is happening here could be one of two things:

1. The function is failing to reserve the additional memory and failing, causing the error you see, and keeping the memory low, as the request for more caused the JVM to crash.
2. You're exhausting only the Metaspace, which @jstell points out is only 10% of the total memory, and you're only using 56MB of heap space.

When you go to a larger memory footprint, it is increasing your metaspace allocation, which enables the function to run.