# AWS Lambda with spark library gives OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, apache-spark, aws-lambda, out-of-memory, parquet

I am trying to use following spark libraries in my aws lambda:

```
implementation "org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.12:2.4.6"
implementation "org.apache.spark:spark-sql_2.12:2.4.6"
```

I ran Lambda initially with memory: 576 MB and then 1024 MB. Both times it failed with:

```
Metaspace: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace
at lambdainternal.AWSLambda.<clinit>(AWSLambda.java:65)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
at lambdainternal.LambdaRTEntry.main(LambdaRTEntry.java:150)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace
Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace
```

It ran successfully when ran with memory size: 2048 MB

I would like to know what is the actual memory size needed to use spark in AWS lambda. Is there any lighter version of the library. I am using this library to create Parquet file and upload it to S3.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely don't want to include Spark as a dependency in a Lambda function.  Spark is way too heavy for Lambda.  Spark should be run on a cluster and Lambda isn't a cluster.

If you want to run serverless Spark code, check out [AWS Glue](https://aws.amazon.com/glue/)... or don't cause AWS Glue is relatively complicated to use.

If your file is sufficiently small to be converted to Parquet in a Lambda function, check out [AWS Data Wrangler](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-data-wrangler).  The [releases](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-data-wrangler/releases) contain pre-built layers, so you don't need to worry about all the low level details for building Layers (figuring out numpy & PyArrow is really annoying - just use the lib).

Here's the code that writes out a Parquet file:

```py
import awswrangler as wr
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"id": [1, 2], "value": ["foo", "boo"]})

# Storing data on Data Lake
wr.s3.to_parquet(
    df=df,
    path="s3://bucket/dataset/",
    dataset=True,
    database="my_db",
    table="my_table"
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The amount of memory you allocate to your java lambda function is shared by **heap, meta, and reserved code memory.**

you can consider increasing only `-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize` size because as per your exception log **Metaspace: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace** issue is related to metaspace

you can custom tune by increasing only metaspace without changing heap and buffer space. (note: spark might be loading a lot of classes and utilizing metaspace) and please also consider running your spark app in [cluster mode](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html).

you can check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35298616/aws-lambda-and-inaccurate-memory-allocation)

for more info about [heap memory,metaspace and reserved code memory](https://jkutner.github.io/2017/04/28/oh-the-places-your-java-memory-goes.html#:%7E:text=JVM%20Memory%20Categories&text=Heap%20%2D%20The%20heap%20is%20where,or%20%E2%80%9CObjects%E2%80%9D%20are%20stored.&text=Metaspace%20%2D%20Metaspace%20stores%20the%20Class,improve%20performance%20by%20reusing%20it.).

Comment: This is a good suggestion in a different execution context, but not the best here because Spark should always be avoided in AWS Lambda.